# Cancel In app Billing Subscription in android

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase, upgrade, in-app-billing

In my app , there is functionality called in app subscription which is auto renewal . In app there is a feature called "Cancel Upgrade".

What I want is If user cancel the **subscription** then his/her subcription will be cancelled not refundable but just cancelled.

I go through this [link](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_admin.html) and found below note:

**You cannot use the API to issue refunds or cancel In-app Billing transactions. You must do this manually through your Google payments merchant account. However, you can use the API to retrieve order information.**

But i want my user to cancel his/her upgrade.

Is there any way to do this or please provide alternate solution for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you try to cancel it automatically from your Google play developer console ?

Comment: No i want to give that access to user.

Answer (score 10):

From the [in app subscription guide](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions.html),

> Users can view the status of all of their subscriptions and cancel
>   them if necessary from the My Apps screen in the Play Store app.
>   Currently, the In-app Billing API does not provide support for
>   programatically canceling subscriptions from inside the purchasing
>   app.

Thus, the user won't be able to cancel their subscription from the app itself, but you can invite them to viist the My Apps section on the Play Store to cancel it.

Answer (score 9):

You can try [Google Play Developer API](https://developer.android.com/google/play/developer-api.html#subscriptions_api_overview), a REST-based web service that includes [Subscriptions and In-App Purchases API](https://developer.android.com/google/play/developer-api.html#subscriptions_api_overview)

[Purchases.subscriptions: cancel](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions/cancel)

> Cancels a user's subscription purchase. The subscription remains valid
>   until its expiration time.

[User Billing](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions.html)

> Google Play provides a purchase token back to the purchasing app
>   through the In-app Billing API. Your apps can store the token locally
>   or pass it to your backend servers, which can then use it to validate
>   or cancel the subscription remotely using the Google Play Developer
>   API.

Comment: Thanks for the answer . I will try it and let you know.

Comment: I think this is a HUGE security risk. The GP Developer API are to easy your publication/management process, not to be put into an app. If the app apk or the request sent are analyzed, an attacker would basically obtain access to your GP Developer Console. Or is there something I've missed?

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer.

Comment: @AndreaBasso you're actually right assuming one would call the Google Play Developer API directly from the App. However, you can get around this when having your own backend inbetween.

Comment: @Andrea He means to say that you can set up your own back-end server and that server can then use Purchases.subscriptions:cancel to cancel a subscription.